# How to Update ViewPager from inside OnClickListener?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using SwipeCards Library and the main code is inside an array adapter. An Activity (BaseCardsActivity) fecthes some data from Firebase, passes it to an ArrayAdapter (SwingAdapterClass). There are some images inside this Adapter and, when user clicks one of them, this ImageView disappears and an Interface (not shown here) fetches some images dependingo on the img the user clicked and loads them all to a ViewPager.

The problem is: I need to load the Viewpager from inside the OnClickListener method attached to each ImageView (the reason is too long, and this question is already too long), so I can request Firebase only if user clicks the img.

However, from inside OnClickListener, the ViewPager is not loading. From outside the OnClickListener it does works, like I show in the example.

I've provided a leaner example of the logic, or this post would be too long. I ask for your help, please. Sorry I'm so bad editing code here.

Thank you.

BaseCardsActivity.java

```
//implement the onFlingListener
public class BaseCardsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_cards);
       //mAuth, DatabaseReference, etc.

        rowItem = new ArrayList<CardsModel>();
        mAdapterClass = new SwingAdapterClass(BaseCardsActivity.this, R.layout.cards,rowItem);
 final SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
  //  flingContainer.setAdapter(mAdapterClass);
    flingContainer.setAdapter(mViewpagerEvents);
        instantiateSwipeCards();

}

private void instantiateSwipeCards(){
   mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    //datasnapshot....
    // get all images I need
    // put images in List<String> imgList

    CardsModel cards = new CardsModel(imgList);
    rowItem.add(cardsModel);

    mAdapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
}
```

activity_base_cards.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffeee9e2"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
        tools:context=".BaseCardsActivity"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

SwingAdapterClass.java

```
public class SwingAdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter<CardsModel>{

 public SwingAdapterClass(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<CardsModel> item) {
        super(context, resource, item);
        mContext = context;    
  }

 @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final CardsModel cardsModel = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);
        }


   mPager = convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
      mImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.Id.clickImg);
      mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                    
mCircleImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                  
mPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


 /*====this code outside OnClickListener Works   ====*/
      mProfileViewPagerAdapter = new ProfileViewPagerAdapter(mContext, cardsModel.getCreatorGallery());                    



 mPager.setAdapter(mProfileViewPagerAdapter);

    /*=======  ======*/

            }
        });

   }


  private class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private List<String> mListData= new ArrayList<String>();


        public ViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> listData){
            mContext = context;
            mListData = listData;
            notifyDataSetChanged();    
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.d(tag, Integer.toString(mListData.size()));
            return mListData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
          ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, container, false);
           final ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.theImg);
            Log.d(tag, Integer.toString(mListData.size()));

          Glide.with(mContext).load(mListData.get(position)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true).into(imageView);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }    
    }   
}
```

Layout for ArrayAdapter:

cards.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/empty_profile"
    android:id="@+id/clickImg"/>
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
           android:visibility="invisible">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
   mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {     

             new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   mCircleImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                  
                    mPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              mProfileViewPagerAdapter = new ProfileViewPagerAdapter(mContext, cardsModel.getCreatorGallery());      

         mPager.setAdapter(mProfileViewPagerAdapter);

          }
        });

      }
     });
```

And also tried to inflate the Viewpager from Inside OnClickListener, if that makes any sense:

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {     

                 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                 View v =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);

                  mPager = v.findViewById(R.id.vpag);
                       mCircleImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                  
                        mPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                  mProfileViewPagerAdapter = new ProfileViewPagerAdapter(mContext, cardsModel.getCreatorGallery());      

             mPager.setAdapter(mProfileViewPagerAdapter);

              }
            });

          }
         });
```

Comment: Try wrapping it in `Handler().post()`.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it right now.

Comment: @TheWanderer I updated the question. Please, see if that's what you meant. Same result.